# Rspec post request rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, grape-api

I want to test my create action at `api/v1/posts` with `rspec`

api was built with `grape`

so i have tried

```
    post 'api/v1/posts', params: { post: { name: 'name', body: 'body', published_at: Date.today } }
```

but i have got

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
```

Full error trace

```
params = { name: 'name', body: 'body', published_at: Date.today }        
=> {:name=>"name", :body=>"body", :published_at=>Wed, 31 May 2017}

[91] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::APIV1Posts::Anonymous::HTTPRequestToPostAPI>)> post 'api/v1/posts', params: params        
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)

from /Users/stas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:298:in `block in let'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: is that the line throwing the error ?, are you sure is not a different one ?

Comment: @fanta updated quiz

Comment: looks like you are using `let` in the wrong way ?

Comment: I see, you're doing the request while debugging the code.

Comment: are you by any means defining a `post` variable somewhere ?, like `let(:post) { }`